# How to allow the user to close a searchDisplayController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here is what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, by default there is no way to get out of this view unless the user taps a row in the TableView, in which case you can dismiss the view.  If only there was some way I could intercept the cancel button press that would be a way, but I'm not sure it's possible.

So, my question is, how can I allow the user to cancel out of this modal view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate methods to the rescue: why don't you set up a delegate for the search display controller's `searchBar`, and implement [`searchBarCancelButtonClicked:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarCancelButtonClicked%3a)? You'll have to give the delegate a reference back to the display controller; or, better, the display controller could itself be the delegate.

Or am I missing something about your question?

Comment: There we are.  That's the method I was looking for, I just didn't know the name.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @sudo: Always look for a delegate protocol when you find yourself saying "Dang, if I could just know when _x_ happens to _obj_!". The Cocoa engineers, they are pretty smart. ;) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could either wrap your modal tableview controller in a navigation controller and add a done button to your table view controller's navigation item or implement the UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate method:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what `WillBeginSearch` has to do with it.  That's not called when the cancel button is tapped. Maybe you misunderstood me, I don't mean I want the keyboard hidden, I mean I want the whole view to be dismissed when the cancel button is tapped.